# Finding the path of the particle in a region of the plane.

Tags: geometry, ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, partial-derivative

I am not sure how to continue this.

What I've done is said that r'(t)= -(gradientp)(r(t)) where r(t) is the path taken by the particle.
Should I now split the equation into x and y components to get two ODE's?
How can I continue this?

[image]

Comment: Try writing the function as $p(x,y)=(x-1/2)^2+3(y-1/3)^2$ (a parabaloid) and using that the negative gradient points in the direction of greatest decrease. You can think of the negative gradient flow as sliding down the parabaloid towards the minimum.

Comment: @Khanickus I still cannot relate. I know the -gradient of p and the factorisation you gave me, but how can I find r(t) which is essentially the path of the particle?

Comment: I guess to find $r(t)$ exactly you would need to solve the differential equations. But to just sketch the path you can draw some level curves of $p$ (ellipses centered at (1/2, 1/3)) then use that the path is always passing through these ellipses perpendicularly since it follows the negative gradient. It will be a curve going from (1,1) to (1/2,1/3) (since the ellipses are closing in on (1/2,1/3)).

Comment: @Khanickus Thanks, understood that part. However I seem unable to set up the required differential equations. How could I do that?

Comment: Ahh, ok I thought you where asking about the following parts. I think your idea in your question sounds good, as in split into x and y components to get $(x',y')=-\nabla p(x,y)=(1-2x, 2-6y)$ which is the two uncoupled equations $x'=1-2x$ and $y'=2-6y$ with $x(0)=y(0)=1$.